# Printing a chessboard row

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to create a function for a game but I'm having some problems with the body. I'm creating a function that returns a string by using the parameters of the function. According to my function I need to return the characters from the row of the `board` (parameter1) with index `row_index` (Parameter2) as a single string.
Any help will be useful. Ty
This is my function head and body:

```
def make_str_from_row(board, row_index):
    """ (list of list of str, int) -> str

    # Return the characters from the row of the board with index row_index
    as a single string.

    >>> make_str_from_row([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 0)
    'ANTT'
    """
    for i in range(len(row_index) - 1):
        if board[i]  row_index[i]
        return board[i]
```

Comment: What does it do at the moment?

Comment: @PeterWood: my guess is that it will throw a syntax error because of the weird `if` statement.

Comment: Is `row_index` an integer? You can only use `len` on sequences, like lists. `board` is a list.

Comment: @PeterWood: based on the documentation, I guess. But the program does not make the slightest sense at all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really do not see what you aim to do by using `for` loops, etc.

you can simply fetch the row at `row_index` with:

```
board[row_index]
```

and the joining of the characters can be done with - guess what - [`.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
def make_str_from_row(board, row_index):
    return ''.join(board[row_index])
```

Here `''` is the *separator*: the string that is put between the characters. Since we do not want to put any characters in between, it is the empty string. `join` takes as parameter an iterable of strings, here the list of characters of that row and join them together. So if you feed `''.join(..)` a list of strings like:

```
''.join(['Foo','Bar','Qux','Hello','World'])
```

it will return:

```
'FooBarQuxHelloWorld'
```

Comment: @PaulRooney: thanks for pointing that out. Perhaps these fingers are too used to Dutch.

Comment: could you teach me how .join works in my function pls?

Comment: @KennethRivadeneiraGuadamud: what part of the answer is unclear at that point?

Comment: i didnt know .join function so I would know how it would work in my function? I am learning how to use python3 by myselft but sometimes I cant really understand some aspects.

Comment: @KennethRivadeneiraGuadamud: `join` is part of the functions attached to strings as you can find here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join Why would it not work in a particular function?

Comment: ohh! thank you. I didnt know thaat website. I think will be very useful.

Comment: There are lots more links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info)